# Can I control C# Visual Studio (for Unity) code from the command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, command-prompt, hololens

I wish to not use my Unity or Visual Studio applications at all, and either hide or show a hologram (working with Hololens here) using Command Prompt. This should be just setting a boolean true or false, but I don't want to edit the Visual Studio C# code.

Comment: You want to edit a runtime variable in your application via command line?

Comment: @Master117 yes; I am new at Unity and VS, but my end goal is to manipulate hologram displays without having to edit the code manually. so I thought I would start with trying to edit via the command line

Comment: Assuming you want to make zero changes to the code you can only inject into your code or memory edit your code.

Comment: How about adding a button or hotkey that changes the bool to your app?

Comment: Or open a console window (from your app) and read input?

Comment: @Master117 This is what VS and Unity want me to do, I know, (use a button) but I wanted to use cmd to try to specifically not do what VS and Unity want if that makes sense. Because eventually, I won't have a button, and the only input would be either voice or gestures.

Comment: You can edit your code and rebuild via the command line without opening an IDE.

Comment: Master has given you excellent suggestion.  Do that, and tick the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be looking at the HoloToolkit Sharing components.

You can use a Win 10 app to control the holograms and for a simple scenario like yours it would be very simple to achieve. 
In summary, you drag a sharing prefab from HoloToolkit, you configure the server ip (localhost in your case), and you write some code to respond to whatever message you choose.

Here are some resources to get you started:

1. [HoloLens Academy 240](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_240)
2. [HoloToolkit Sharing GitHub Master](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit)

   - check the `SessionManager.UI` or `SessionManagerUniversal.UI` projects.

It sounds a bit complicated, but it will open up a lot of doors in the future if you ever need to expand your solution further.

Answer (score -1):

Write code that polls (checks) a file continually. Like

```
void Update()
{
    if(File.ReadAllText("a.txt") == "activate")
        myBool = true;
}
```

And change your file from commandline or whatever:

```
echo activate > a.txt
```

Note: This is just a method that requires very little changes. It's not the best performancewise.

Comment: you could also write code that uses the webcam to take pictures continuously and do OCR recognition on them, looking for the word "activate". When it finds this word, it changes the bool. Then point the camera at your printer, then create a simple console app that prints the word "activate" in large font size when run. Then run that app from the console to enable the bool...

Comment: @irreal You got a better proposal for how to do this via commandline? I already suggestes hotkeys and other performant solutions. I even suggested waiting for cmd input.